# Script Shell Find each occurrence of a String in a file

Tags: ubuntu, script

Here is the structure of my file:

```
/**** Some Text here ****/                         
DN  10.147.243.93  51.46 KB   256     34.2%
DN  10.147.243.89  83.05 KB   256     34.6%
DN  10.147.243.88  66.43 KB   256     32.7%
```

Here is my script

```
file=$1
echo $file
ip=$(grep -e  DN $1 | awk '{ print $2; }')
echo $ip
```

output:

```
StateNodes.txt
10.147.243.93 10.147.243.89 10.147.243.88
```

Please, how can I modify my script, I want to do a treatment with each occurrence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that I understand your requirements then store the ip addresses in an array and reference each element

```
    iparr=($(awk '/^DN/ {print $2}' StateNodes.txt))
```

Show the elements in the array:

```
    echo ${iparr[@]}
```

List the elements in the array:

```
    for e in ${iparr[@]}
    do echo "$e"
    done
```

List the first element in the array

```
    echo ${iparr[0]}
```

Comment: I'd like to store each ip address in a variable. echo $ip  echo $ip1 echo $ip 2 .............echo $ipn